# How can I iterate over every week in a year in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-time

Apologies in advance if I confuse any ISO date related terms here.

I would like to be able to iterate over every week in a given year (say, 2015). I realize that you can calculate the number of weeks between 1/1/2015 and 12/31/2015, but that doesn't conform to the ISO standard of a week. Rather, it gives the number of 7 day periods between two dates. The first ISO week of the year doesn't necessarily start on 1/1/2015.

If I can get the first date of the first week, I believe I can simply iterate via `ZonedDateTime.plusWeeks(1)` for 52 weeks. You can get the week number of an *arbitrary* date via the field accessor:

```
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.now();
WeekFields weekFields = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault());
int weekNumber = date.get(weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear());
```

Given this, I think it must be possible to get the date of the first day of the first week of a *specific* year in the Java8 Time API, but I have not found a way to do it yet.

Comment: See also [my examples](http://time4j.net/tutorial/appendix.html#x14) for constructing a ISO-week-date in different libraries. Even old JDK with `java.util.GregorianCalendar` is apparently simpler because JSR-310 (java.time-package) lacks a simple factory method here..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can construct a date and adjust it to the first day of week for the first week of the year with the following:

```
int year = 2016;
WeekFields weekFields = WeekFields.ISO;
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now().with(weekFields.weekBasedYear(), year)
                                .with(weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), 1)
                                .with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
```

Thanks to [JodaStephen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen)'s comment, another way to put it would be to use the [`IsoFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html) class.

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now().with(IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR, year)
                                .with(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, 1)
                                .with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
```

[`WeekFields.ISO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#ISO) represents the ISO definition of the week:

> The ISO-8601 definition, where a week starts on Monday and the first week has a minimum of 4 days.
>
> The ISO-8601 standard defines a calendar system based on weeks. It uses the week-based-year and week-of-week-based-year concepts to split up the passage of days instead of the standard year/month/day.
>
> Note that the first week may start in the previous calendar year. Note also that the first few days of a calendar year may be in the week-based-year corresponding to the previous calendar year.

From that definition, you can get:

- [`weekBasedYear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#weekBasedYear--) represents the week-based-year field:

  > This represents the concept of the year where weeks start on a fixed day-of-week, such as Monday and each week belongs to exactly one year.

  In this case, we want to set it to the wanted year.
- [`weekOfWeekBasedYear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#weekOfWeekBasedYear--) represents the week of week-based-year

  > This represents the concept of the count of weeks within the year where weeks start on a fixed day-of-week, such as Monday and each week belongs to exactly one year.

  In this case, we want the first week of the week-based-year so we set it to 1.
- [`ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#DAY_OF_WEEK) which represents the day of the week. In this case, we want the first day of the week so we set to 1.

Then, with such a date, you can indeed iterate over all weeks of the year by calling [`LocalDate.plusWeeks(1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusWeeks-long-). The question is: how many times do you need to iterate? There can be more than 52 weeks in a year. There are either 52 or 53 weeks in a week-based-year.

You can retrieve the number of weeks with the following. This call [`rangeRefinedBy(date)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalField.html#rangeRefinedBy-java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor-) to retrieve the valid values of the week of year field for the given date, and get its maximum.

```
long maxWeekOfYear = weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear().rangeRefinedBy(date).getMaximum();
```

Comment: You need `weekOfWeekBasedYear()` and `weekBasedYear()`, not `weekOfYear()` and `dayOfWeek()`. The two are different. In this case however, what would make more sense is to use `IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR` and `IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR` which would avoid the confusion.

Comment: @JodaStephen Could you expand a little? I tested with year 2010 to 2020 and the result seemed correct but I admit having trouble sometimes with all those definitions :) (and I didn't know `IsoFields` even existed...).

Comment: `weekOfYear()` operates within a calendar year. `weekOfWeekBasedYear()` operates within a `weekBasedYear()` (the first day of a week-based-year might be in the previous calendar year, and the last day might be in the next calendar year). Since the OP asks about ISO week-based-years, you need the week-based-year methods.

Comment: @JodaStephen Thanks a lot for your input, I edited with that.